# Is the empty tag reaper not working, or is the [workaround] tag magic?

Tags: support, tags, historical-lock

There's a process that runs every night and removes tags that have no answers attached.

There's also a set of horrible awful no-good tags that I make sure to keep dead.

Like [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/workaround).

Take note that it has a wiki excerpt.  I created that excerpt six months ago.

*Six months*.

Has it really been used every day for six months, or is the tag reaper not reaping it?

I know that there were some recent changes to *other* tag reapers that had to do with tag wikis.  The reapers used to consume any tag that had only one question attached over a period of time, but now they'll keep the tag around if a wiki was added.  Is it possible that *empty* tags with wikis are no longer reaped?

Comment: There is still a question somewhere that has this tag on it. The synonyms page says 1 question and my merge preview says it will affect 1 question but I can't find it.

Comment: @animuson: I found it, it is a locked question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3076414/2619912

Comment: Weird.  Now, why doesn't that question show up?  Does the historic lock hide questions from the tag list entirely?

Comment: @Charles: Yes, a historical lock hides them from the tag list, but you can still find them using a search.

Comment: [Search with `locked:1` to find these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131593); http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bworkaround%5D+locked%3A1 works.

Comment: And Animuson has removed the tag. Super-edit-powas for the win!

Comment: From the revision history, it looks like diamond mods can just edit, no need to unlock/relock.  Thanks, @animuson!